# Run commands in a terminal, then let me type more commands

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, gnome-terminal

I wrote this script to create multiple tabs in the same terminal window and run commands in them:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Use the commands as:
#--tab-with-profile=Default --title=<SPECIFY THE TAB TITLE HERE> -e "bash -ic \"<SPECIFY THE COMMAND YOU WANT TO RUN HERE>; bash\"" \
#The ampersand in the end of this file makes sure that the gnome-terminal command is run as a background process

echo "Setting up simulator environment";
service mysqld start;

gnome-terminal \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=PROG1 -e "bash -ic \"clear;ls;./prog1; bash disown\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=SIMULATOR -e "bash -ic \"clear;ls;./simulator; bash disown\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=PROG2 -e "bash -ic \"clear;ls;./prog2; bash disown\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=DATA -e "bash -ic \"./data -f \"/home/user/NetBeansProjects/data3.txt\" -p \"6785\"; bash disown\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=PROG3 -e "bash -ic \"cd /home/user/NetBeansProjects/simulator;./prog3; bash disown\"" \
&
```

Problem is, when any of those programs finish running or if I press `Ctrl+c` to stop any of those programs, the tab closes. I don't want the tab to close. **I want the tab to remain open and the bash terminal to be shown so that I can run some other command in the tab**. Is there a way to make that happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems;

The first one is that inside each `bash -ic` command (which by the way doesn't spawn an interactive shell because `-c` overrides `-i`, so `-i` it's safe to be dropped) you're calling `bash disown` instead of `bash`, which means nothing and immediately exits on error; so there's no interactive shell keep running that keeps `gnome-terminal` opened at the end of the outer `bash -c` command;

(Also mind that you could use `exec bash` instead of `bash` at the end of the command, to save some processes.)

The second one is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> SIGINTs all the processess in the same group of the killed process, including the parent `bash` instance which is supposed to spawn the interactive shell at the end of the command;

To fix this, you can use `bash`'s `trap` built-in to set `bash` to spawn another interactive `bash` instance upon the reception of a SIGINT signal.

In short, this should work:

```
gnome-terminal \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=PROG1 -e "bash -c \"trap 'bash' 2; clear;ls;./prog1; exec bash\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=SIMULATOR -e "bash -c \"trap 'bash' 2; clear;ls;./simulator; exec bash\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=PROG2 -e "bash -c \"trap 'bash' 2; clear;ls;./prog2; exec bash\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=DATA -e "bash -c \"trap 'bash' 2; ./data -f \"/home/user/NetBeansProjects/data3.txt\" -p \"6785\"; exec bash\"" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=PROG3 -e "bash -c \"trap 'bash' 2; cd /home/user/NetBeansProjects/simulator;./prog3; exec bash\"" \
&
```

Comment: Awesome! The new `bash` terminal causes the assigned title of the tab to disappear, so a solution to that would make the script perfect. I tried `bash --tab -t "X"` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Nav Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446041/setting-terminal-tab-titles); personally I'd avoid the first solution; the exact same thing can be done using the second solution or the third solution; the second one is a bit "invasive", as it will affect any `gnome-terminal` instance and any XTerm compatible terminal; personally I would go for the third option and setup a custom profile.

Comment: Works! Had to go to the `Edit` menu of the terminal, `Profiles` > `Default`. And for the option of `When terminal commands set their own titles`, I selected `Keep initial title`. Thank you very much @kos.

Comment: @Nav You're welcome, glad that it helped.