# Execute a command in a separate konsole then let users type commands

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, tcsh, csh, konsole

I am working on software at a large corporation where I have little control over the overall technologies used, and as a result need to find solutions that will work within the constraints I have.

**What I'm working on:** I'm developing a UI that lets users launch konsoles with specific environments based on the projects they are working on. We currently have a command (let's call it "setContext") that users run in their konsole manually with a lot of arguments. setContext does a lot of work and sets a lot of environment variables.
As part of my constraints, I have to use konsole, tcsh, and this setContext command.
All my UI needs to do is compose the setContext command with the proper arguments, open a konsole, and run that command for the user, after what they will be in control.

The command I generate is something like:

`konsole -e tcsh -c "setContext --someArgs"`

This works, but closes the konsole right away. Using the `--noclose` option when launching the konsole keeps it open but not interactive.

The commonly accepted solution to this problem, is to append `;bash` or `;$SHELL` at the end of the command, in my case I have extrapolated it to be `;tcsh`.

This is what is suggested in the following links, and many others:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal/1209836#1209836
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the
- [Run commands in a terminal, then let me type more commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234247/run-commands-in-a-terminal-then-let-me-type-more-commands)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/484993/run-command-on-anothernew-terminal-window

This nearly works, as it does indeed keep the konsole open. In fact this is what I have been using for weeks without troubles, however we have noticed that running `tcsh` after `setContext` sources all the initialization files again (~/.cshrc, etc..), which resets some of the variables set by `setContext`.

This needs to work for hundreds of users, and I have no control over the cshrc files, so I need to find a way to keep the konsole open without sourcing these again. I tried `tcsh -f` but that doesn't preserve the environment.

I have been searching online all afternoon but haven't managed to find a solution. While I understand environments and commands okay, I am no expert and usually work in python. I am resorting to ask here because everything I'm finding is either a re-hash of the answer above, requires to modify cshrc files, or is way above my level and I can't decipher it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> running `tcsh` after `setContext` sources all the initialization files again (`~/.cshrc`, etc..), which resets some of the variables set by `setContext`.

You could trick `tcsh` into not reading the `~/.cshrc` by pointing the `HOME` environment variable to some other directory containing a `.cshrc` which resets `HOME` to its original value, sources the user's `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc`, and then calls your `setContext`.

Example, using `/fake/home` as the decoy home directory:

```
konsole -e sh -c 'REAL_HOME=$HOME HOME=/fake/home exec tcsh'
```

with `/fake/home/.cshrc` containing:

```
setenv HOME "$REAL_HOME"
if (-f ~/.tcshrc) then
   source ~/.tcshrc
else if (-f ~/.cshrc) then
   source ~/.cshrc
endif
setContext
# other aliases and initializations
```

---

Yes, this is a horrible kludge. Find something better ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I considered doing it this way, however other software that we are launching from that konsole will rely on the $HOME variable. One thing I thought about overnight is that I may be able to use `setContext` in a temporary .cshrc or something similar, so that I don't actually run the command, but somehow inject it into the start up of the konsole.  EDIT: Oh I see what you did here, you set it back to the real home. Sadly I have no control over `/etc/.cshrc`

Comment: This is a good idea, thank you. In the meantime I found a possible alternative using `qdbus` to interface with konsole. I need a bit more time to ensure everything works as expected, and if it does I will post an alternate answer. I have upvoted yours but apparently votes by newbies do not show.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround I'd like to share is somebody else is in the same situation as I am, is to use `qdbus` to send commands to another instance of konsole.

It's can be a bit convoluted because in my case I needed to know the Konsole's pid, but it did the trick.

- https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/scripting.html
- https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/start-and-control-konsole-dbus

I think I will still use user431397's method in the end because qdbus often gives a warning when sending commands, which could be removed by recompiling, but it's not something I can do, and the warning is annoying me.

I have also discovered `yakuake` while researching dbus, and it turned out to be installed here, and is easier to control with qdbus than konsole is.